# cannt using int value Inside a string code?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do is find a value and try to pass it inside the text function and the more i put the variable $index error occurs although everything is intact, i use php 7, but I don't know why.

```
$index = 2;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = . ($index) .";
$rows = $db->query($sql,[1]);

$filters = json_decode($rows);

foreach($filters as $obj){

   $filter_id[] = $obj->tokens;
}


print_r($filter_id[0]);
```

Error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: filter_id in
>   **/storage/ssd3/402/3009402/public_html/sendNotifaction.php** on
>   line **37**

Comment: 1. `var_dump($sql);` 2. Then switch to using prepared statements instead 3. Why do you have `json_decode` there

Comment: Try `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $index";`

Comment: Thanks for you now i put your code then remove  problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Your concatenation is incorrect:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = . ($index) .";
```

It should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =" . $index;
```

or:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ={$index}";
```

#### 2. You haven't initialized `$filter_id`:

```
$filter_id = [];
foreach($filters as $obj){
   $filter_id[] = $obj->tokens;
}
```

Try to read the errors you get, they usually tell you what the problem is.

#### 3. How to use the query result

Read how [the query function should be used](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). You may have to use `->fetch_assoc()` in your case.